# angular ag-grid insert dropdown list into custom header

Tags: angular, dropdown, ag-grid

Current behavior

I use ag-grid angular to build a inifinity scrolling grid, and insert my custom header into it, I added a dropdown list, but the list cannot show well because of the header height. I mean if I make the header higher, the list can show well, but not in the regular height
Expected behavior

but now I do not want to use the default column menu, I want to insert my dropdown list including "sorting /filtering..." items
Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgQqG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oiwm6.png)

Please tell us about your environment:

Operating system: Windows
IDE: VS official
package manager:Angular-cli
HTTP server:HTTP Module

ag-grid-angular version: 2.0.X
ag-Grid/ag-Grid-Enterprise version: 2.0.X
"ag-grid-angular": "^16.0.0"

Angular version: 2.0.X
"": "4.2.x",

Browser: [all | Chrome XX | Firefox XX | IE XX | Safari XX | Mobile Chrome XX | Android X.X Web Browser | iOS XX Safari | iOS XX UIWebView | iOS XX WKWebView ]
Chrome

Language: [all | TypeScript X.X | ES6/7 | ES5]
all

Comment: please add your code in plunker or stackblitz, it is very difficult to understand with the description where are you and what you want. Thank you!!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bH7QXnKVIgVv1M0UP9Dq?p=preview

Comment: but I don't know why it not showing ....

Comment: I tried to look at your code on plunkr. Is your code public on github?